# "Your package name is not valid" on Android connection to DEEZER

Tags: java, android, path, stream, deezer

I'm trying to establish a connection from an android device to the music-streaming-platform deezer. I followed the developers tutorial but already in the beginning there is trouble.

Building the connection works fine, anyway there are'nt any failures in the log.

```
connection = new DeezerConnectImpl(this, APP_ID);
```

On calling the connection to authorize with

```
connection.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new ReconnectDialogHandler());
```

a new (and mysterious?) screen appears in the device-emulator showing this message:

[image]

I searched on the developers-page and the internet for a possible solution, but i found nothing helpful... 
What's the matter of this fault..?

Here's the complete code:

```
package com.example.deezertest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerConnect;
import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerConnectImpl;
import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerError;
import com.deezer.sdk.DialogError;
import com.deezer.sdk.DialogListener;
import com.deezer.sdk.OAuthException;
import com.deezer.sdk.SessionStore;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final String SECRET = "XXXXX";
public String access_token = "XXXXX";
private final String APP_ID = "XXXXX";
private final static String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"basic_access","offline_access"};
private static final String LOG_TAG = "BaseActvt";
DeezerConnect connection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();

    System.out.println("onCreate");

    connection = new DeezerConnectImpl(this, APP_ID);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void loginButton(View view){
    System.out.println("Button clicked");
    connection.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new ReconnectDialogHandler());
}


protected class ReconnectDialogHandler implements DialogListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(final Bundle values) {
        SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();
        sessionStore.save( connection, MainActivity.this );
        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, R.string.user_authentified, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }//met

    @Override
    public void onDeezerError(final DeezerError deezerError) {
        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, R.string.deezer_error_during_login, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        Log.e( LOG_TAG, "DialogError error during login" , deezerError );
    }//met

    @Override
    public void onError(final DialogError dialogError) {
        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, R.string.deezer_error_during_login, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        Log.e( LOG_TAG, "DialogError error during login", dialogError );
    }//met

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, R.string.login_cancelled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }//met

    @Override
    public void onOAuthException(OAuthException oAuthException) {
        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, R.string.invalid_credentials, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }//met


}//inner class

}
```

And the error-log:

[image]

Here's the Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.deezertest2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.deezertest2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you post the AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- go on deezer developer page
- do login go in your registered APP page ,
- edit your application and you will see an "Android application" down
  on the page.
- Set there the "Android Package Name" to com.example.deezertest2

P.S: Hackitaly , isn't it? :D

Comment: oh lord....... that's it. I think it's hard for you to see me struggle  on this simple point.. :D thank you sir !

Comment: amazing solution